# The use of the word "dynamic" for interpretation on graphs

Tags: meaning

How to use ***the word "dynamic"*** in terms of the graph, and can I refer to this as ***a line*** on time series. For instance:
***"The dynamic for the population of bears has experienced a significant increase in recent years."***
Is this usage correct or not?

[image]

Comment: The population of bears has experienced a significant increase.  What is the “dynamic” for a population?

Comment: @Jim Appreciate you, sir

Comment: It is not easy to research this question from the rather specific viewpoint of the questioner. He gives an example and asks a reasonable question (ignoring the relevant but secondary *line* issue). Leave open.

Answer (score 1):

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dynamic)
>
> dynamic: noun
> a force or factor that controls or influences a process of growth, change, interaction, or activity : a dynamic force or factor
> a social/cultural/interpersonal dynamic
> … describes a world order that seems to be evolving from ideology as the principal dynamic …
> — Woody West
> Denial has always been the most devastating social and political dynamic of the AIDS epidemic …

The dynamics for population increase may therefore include disease reduction, food increase, habitat expansion, reduction of hunting, predator decline. Each or any or these are the factors influencing population.

In the case of your bears, the graph merely shows that the *population* is increasing. It tells nothing about the factors driving the increase. Your graph should therefore not be labelled with *dynamic*.

In mathematics, a line is generally understood to be the shortest distance between two points. Your image therefore contains *several* different lines that join the measurement points and might be better described as *a graph that shows a trend of increase in population.*

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trend)
>
> Trend:
> a general development in a situation or in the way that people behave:

Comment: Appreciate you, sir

Comment: 'The dynamics for population increase may therefore include ...' _Exercise_? _Yogi_?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth An entertaining thought. If we were talking of human population I rather think you could be right. Also consider power blackouts and the consumption of alcohol as less worthy dynamics or factors. But I stray, I stray ...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth More seriously, the dynamics I list are merely the most likely, or standard, ecological ones to influence populations of most animals in the wild.

Comment: Sorry; a failed pun.